# “Communicated” in this context

Tags: meaning

> As he threw his head back in the chair, his glance happened to rest upon a bell, disused bell, that hung in the room, and communicated, for some purpose now forgotten, with a chamber in the highest story of the building.

In this sentence, I don't get the 'communicated' part. Who is communicating with the chamber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s remove some of the extra text that might distract you when analyzing the sentence:

> [...] his glance happened to rest upon a **bell** [...] **that** hung in the room, and **communicated** [...] **with a chamber** in the highest story of the building.

We are basically looking at noun with a relative clause describing its properties:

> a bell that communicated with a chamber

To understand the meaning, you need to understand a bit about life at the time when this was written: 
Dickens’ [A Christmas Carol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol) was published in the mid-nineteenth century when upperclass households employed servants who could be summoned by a system of bells that were connected to bell pulls by long wires. One would pull in one room and the corresponding bell in another room would ring.

So the bell in question is connected to a bell pull in a room in the highest story.